# Gutters overflowing!

Tags: gutters, overflow

My gutters always overflow during even moderate rain. I have large roof sq. footage and steep angle. My gutters are standard 5". I'm thinking i need at least 6". Will this help? Will 7" be even better, or is that too much for a residential home?

Comment: You might need more downspouts to move the water out, though step one is to make sure that everything is clean and unobstructed (I've seen some terrible gutter to downspout connections that interfere with proper flow)

Comment: When is the last time you've cleaned leaves and obstructions out of your gutters?  Do you have anti-leaf covers on the gutters? (those can reduce capacity)  How many square feet of roof do you have, and how many downspouts?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Does the water flow freely into the downspouts?

Answer (score 1):

Larger gutters and screens will not help. Your problem is trees/leaves.Regular cleaning of the gutters with a garden hose may help.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger the gutters and downspouts, the more water it'll carry.
Make sure they are pitched correctly and not clogged and you should be fine.
I'ts not that much of a difference as far as looks go.